# How To Make a Responsive decoration Style With a Div or SVG shape That Touches the left upper edge of the page to the right bottom corner of the page

Tags: html, css

How To Make a Responsive decoration Style With a Div or SVG shape That Touches the left upper edge of the page to the right bottom corner of the page
Like This [enter image description here CLICK ME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N4FW.png)
 or View This Demo : demosamislam.000webhostapp.com
Does anyone Have some Idea on How The Designers can Done That Easily ?
and Does They Use SVG to make decorations on The Body , Or with css or something else ?

Comment: can you share the working demo?

Comment: Yes , ok wait ..

Comment: http://demosamislam.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```css
main{
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
 background-color:gray;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
}
#rotated-box {
 width: 750px ;
 height: 50px;
 background: red;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 position:absolute;
 top:45%;
 left:-25%; 
}
```

```html
<main><div id="rotated-box"></div></main>
```

Comment: You have to adjust its value as per your requirements. Let me know if any problem is coming other than values setting.

Comment: can You Try my Code on Your Editor and Code it for me  ? [no Problem if you can't] .

Comment: you are taking cropped and exact styled image for that cross border style. Instead, go with simple rectangle and then rotate it and apply overflow:hidden. It will be more easy for you.

Comment: I apologize because I was late in answering your message because I went out of the house to work and I had to close my computer .

Comment: Do You Know ? I think this is the best idea to do this

Comment: Welcome, Sam :)

Answer (score 1):

try to make a div and rotate it like so:

```
   div{
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 250%;
  height:250%;
}
```

Comment: no , not that what I meant , I mean How to create The same Thing In The Photo , something Like the Red Div -- in This Photo
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZq8J.png

Comment: Mean : a Responsive decoration Style With a Div or SVG shape That Touches the left upper edge of the page to the right bottom corner of the page